# How to configure log4js to write to a file only if Splunk is down?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, splunk

Currently, our application writes logs to Splunk, and we don't write to a file.

We have a new requirement whereby I need to write logs to a file when, and only when, there are one or more issues in writing directly to Splunk (Splunk is down, Connectivity issue, etc.)

How can I configure log4j2 to write locally if, and only if, the remote Splunk listener is not available?

Comment: Any update guys?

Answer (score 0):

Modify **log4j2.xml**

```
...
<Appenders>
  ...
  <SplunkHttp name="Splunk" ... />
  <RollingFile name="BackupFileLog" ... />
  ...
</Appenders>
...
<Loggers>
  <Root level="INFO">
    <AppenderRef ref="Splunk" />
  </Root>
  <Logger name="BackupFileLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="BackupFileLog" />
  </Logger>
  ...
</Loggers>
```

Prepare **SplunkErrorHandler**

```
public class SplunkErrorHandler implements HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler.ErrorCallback {
  private static Logger BACKUP_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("BackupFileLog");


  public void error(final List<HttpEventCollectorEventInfo> data, final Exception ex) {
    // Here you can forward Splunk error and not delivered messages to BACKUP_LOGGER
    ...
  }
}
```

Inject **SplunkErrorHandler**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler.onError(new SplunkErrorHandler());
    ...
}
```

**Some key points**

- `additivity="false"` in logger is important
- `name="BackupFileLog"` logger should not be binded to class
- `LogManager.getLogger("BackupFileLog")` backup logger should be requested by name